# Как сгенерировать случайно дробное число от 50 до 100 в php?

Tags: php

Для целых чисел использую mt_rand.

А как с помощью этой же функции сгенерировать дробное число?

Comment: Посмотрите ответы на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141212/random-float-between-0-and-1-in-php).

Comment: А для чего, если не секрет?

Answer (score 1):

```
$int = mt_rand(50, 100);
$fractional = mt_rand(1,99) / 100;

$your_number = $int + $fractional;

echo $your_number;
```

[пример sandbox](http:////http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e676f9304733e8bfa6bf08c015318217f8293af9)

Comment: Спасибо, нужно было самому додуматься. Но я пока что новичок)))

Answer (score 1):

Можно и с одним вызовом `mt_rand`

```
$ret = mt_rand(50000, 100000)/1000
```